# Cookie in the contact form only?

Tags: php, cookies, contact-form, setcookie, httpcookie

I found lots of complex replies for complex situations. Mine is simple. I just need a cookie for the page where is located the contact form: set an expiration time (one hour is more than enough). Httponly is important to avoid users to submit edited forms in their local computers. Form must be submitted ONLY filling up the FORM in the URL visited. I have this setting:

```
<?php
$name = 'contacto';
$value = 'spanish-visitor'; 
$expire = time() + 60*60; //One hour enough to fill up a simple form.
$path = '/es/contacto.php'; 
//Or should not put the file name containing the HTML form?

$domain = 'www.mydomain.com'; 
//Or should I put here the specific file where the user lands? like 'www.mydomain.com/es/contacto.php'?

$secure = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']);
$httpOnly = true;
?>
```

For the other pages I don‘t care for cookies, because they are just purely informative. My concern is the contact form which can be target of attacks. It is just a contact form, no login for sessions. I don‘t use CMS. Orientations, please.

Comment: How is XSS involved? This sounds like an XY problem, and likely the real answer is to use a CAPTCHA.

Comment: No. Cookies are domain wide and will be submitted for every request to that domain.